# Npm Install is not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have installed nodejs on ubuntu

```
node -v v0.10.25

npm -v  gives 1.3.10
```

when i run

```
 sudo npm install -g 
or sudo npm install
```

> it gives me following error
>
> 1523 error TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined 1523
>   error     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35) 1523 error
>   at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5 1523 error     at saved
>   (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
>   1523 error     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7 1523
>   error     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15) 1524 error If you need
>   help, you may report this log at:

Any idea ?

why it is giving me this error

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Node.js? I suggest getting the latest version of their source (v4.2.1) from their website, building it locally and then installing it.

Comment: i am installing on ubuntu live machine. apt-get install nodejs

Comment: and i already have project running on locally.  now it gives me errot

  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check all the packages you are trying to install. Some of them might be unpublished from npm.
See this issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4982

Answer (score 4):

There can be two problems:

> 1. You might be using old versions of npm. You can update your client    with
>
>    `npm install npm -g`
> 2. There is a chance that the package you are trying to install had been unpublished from npm :)

Comment: Specifically, the problem I was having was I was installing a package with a scoped name (@flowjs/flow.js).  Scoped package names are not supported in earlier versions of npm.