# Issue is facing during npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

I receive below error while doing npm install.

```
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type non_object_property_load
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

My npm version is 1.3. I have upgraded to this version. Still it is not working. I have read many threads on this issue which are suggesting me to update npm which I already did.

Still no luck. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It is possible that you are using an old version of npm.  Can you try updating npm and retry?

Comment: `npm install npm -g` after try this

Comment: @Dr.Strange I have done this..still the same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm Install is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117626/npm-install-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using an older version of npm.  Try updating it with:

```
npm install npm -g
```

Secondly, one of the packages you are using may have been removed/unpublished from NPM.

Reference: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4982

Comment: Did you try to check the dependencies?